# what encoding unescape() function uses?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

what encoding unescape() function uses ?

I have problem that URL param has utf8 foreign chars, that flash fails to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()`. [More info about functions.](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html)